# Typeorm - Oracle ExecuteOptions

Tags: node.js, oracle, typeorm

Does Typeorm accept specific Oracle parameters when executing the query?

Example:
Oracle

```
const connection = await oracledb.getConnection();
const result = await connection.execute(
      'SELECT QUANTITY FROM mytable WHERE id = :id', 
      { id }, 
      { fetchInfo: {"QUANTITY": {type: oracledb.STRING }}}
)
```

TypeORM

```
const repository = _connection.manager.getRepository(target);
const result = await repository
    .createQueryBuilder('mytable')
    .andWhere('mytable.id = :id', { id })
    .setOptions({ // something like
        fetchInfo: {"QUANTITY": {type: oracledb.STRING }}
    })
    .getMany()
```

I didn't find any parameters that met Oracle's specific options.